# How to sort object that does not match by id inside of array compare to different object inside of an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to sort and leave object inside of an array compare to another array that contains array inside of an object?

Example

```
// first array
const interestsArray = [
  {
    name: 'category1',
    interests: [
      {id:1, name: 'interest1'},
      {id:2, name: 'interest2'},
      {id:3, name: 'interest3'}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'category2',
    interests: [
      {id:4, name: 'interest4'},
      {id:5, name: 'interest5'},
      {id:6, name: 'interest6'},
      {id:7, name: 'interest7'}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'category3',
    interests: [
      {id:8, name: 'interest8'},
      {id:9, name: 'interest9'}
    ]
  }
]

// second array
const myInterestArray = [
  {id:1, name: 'interest1'},
  {id:4, name: 'interest4'},
  {id:6, name: 'interest6'},
  {id:9, name: 'interest9'}
]
```

Desired output after sorting **first array** with **second array** by id:

```
const interestsArray = [
  {
    name: 'category1',
    interests: [
      {id:2, name: 'interest2'},
      {id:3, name: 'interest3'}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'category2',
    interests: [
      {id:5, name: 'interest5'},
      {id:7, name: 'interest7'}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'category3',
    interests: [
      {id:8, name: 'interest8'},
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried it using `forEach`, `filter` and `map` method in one expression but this causes several loops but I am afraid it might cause performance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create a look-up table using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object from your `myInterestsArray`. In the map, each `id` points its associated `name`. Then, you can `.map()` each object in your `interestsArray` to a new object which has a filtered `interests` array. This array is filtered by removing any items which have a given `id` in the look-up pointing to a `name` identical to the one you're iterated on.

See example below:

```js
const interestsArray = [ { name: 'category1', interests: [ {id:1, name: 'interest1'}, {id:2, name: 'interest2'}, {id:3, name: 'interest3'} ] }, { name: 'category2', interests: [ {id:4, name: 'interest4'}, {id:5, name: 'interest5'}, {id:6, name: 'interest6'}, {id:7, name: 'interest7'} ] }, { name: 'category3', interests: [ {id:8, name: 'interest8'}, {id:9, name: 'interest9'} ] } ];
const myInterestArray = [ {id:1, name: 'interest1'}, {id:4, name: 'interest4'}, {id:6, name: 'interest6'}, {id:9, name: 'interest9'} ];

const lut = new Map(myInterestArray.map(({id, name}) => [id, name]));
const res = interestsArray.map(({name, interests}) => ({
     name,
     interests: interests.filter(({id, name}) => lut.get(id) !== name)
   })
);
console.log(res);
```